# Should the server respond one json for all content data on the page in SPA or is better to split it?

Tags: json, api, single-page-application

I'm building API for SinglePageApplication, which handle by Angular in frontend. One thing is not clear to me.
Supose the web applcation has delati journal paige wich display journal,some articles which belongs to this journal and some cool authors which can be not connected to this journal.
Should I build my api urls based on each need page content, for example:
from url `/api/journal/<journal_id>`
send json:

```
{
"journal": {
       "id": 10,
       "name": "new_journal",
       "articles": [
                      {
                      "name": "cool_article",
                      "id": 42
                       },
                       {
                      "name": "another_cool_article",
                      "id": 43
                       }
                   ]
 },
 "authors": [
        {
           "name": "some_name",
           "id": 42
         },
         {
           "name": "another_name",
           "id": 43
          }
            ]
}
```

Or I should build my api based on concrete objects and related objects of them.
With urls like this:
`/api/journals/<journal_id>`
`/api/authors/`
And frontend side build this page with two `GET` requests for fetching content.
Sory if my question too broad, I just want to find best bractice for building API to SinglePageApplications. 
Does it have any difference of building API enpoints for external web-apps and what I should do if page need to display more objects, which not belong together? Which of the options above is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a universal right answer for this. It largely depends on the use case for that data you're fetching. I would say to err on the side of splitting this into multiple requests as it grants you flexibility and efficiency in terms of partial updates to the page. That approach also makes exposing an API to the public much easier in terms of being able to just expose what you already have.

If you're dealing with a potentially large (an intentionally relative term) number of concurrent requests though, you may build some composites of related data to mitigate that.

Of course, you could also do a combination of the two as well (first load makes 1 large request, subsequent updates are segmented).

Comment: Thank a lot for detail answer, I'm really walking in a fog now. I'm found a lot of materials about API building, but no one get a point specific to building SPA application. Maybe you can point me to some resources?

Comment: That is because even though they've been around for quite some time, there aren't really standards associated with bulding a SPA. There are some general ideas and guidelines and not a whole lot else. And the framework you choose carries a lot of weight as well. If you're feeling lost then probably one of the more established frameworks would be a good place to start (i.e. AngularJS 1.x, MeteorJS, etc.). Just follow some tutorials and don't give up!

Comment: thank a lot! actualy I'm diving specialy in server API, working with Django RESTFramework, so I just wanted to use best practice for building smart API for my coworker, wich will hadle it in Angular. I hope I will do it right way :)